# tilesec error with babel

Tags: errors, babel, titlesec

```
\documentclass[ukenglish,10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}  
\usepackage{babel}  
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}  
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Large}{\thechapter}{12mm}{}[\titlerule]  
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{6mm}{1cm}  
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large}{\thesection}{8mm}{}  
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{5mm}{5mm}  
\newpagestyle{main}{  
\sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][(\thesection] % even  
{\thesection)}{\sectiontitle}{\thepage}} % odd  
\begin{document}\pagestyle{main}  
\chapter{C1}  
\section{S1}  
\end{document}
```

generates the

```
"The <format> argument cannot contain horizontal material such as text, \noindent, \makebox, etc."
```

error message at the `\chapter{C1}` command and I don't see why. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug introduced in the 2019-10-01 update of the LaTeX kernel. In this update a handful of commands were made robust, and some packages (such as `babel` in this case) try to redefine these commands. If these redefinitions do not take the new robustness into account, bad things may happen.

The current problem arises because `babel` redefines `\markboth` (without taking into account that it's now robust) and then it mistakenly typesets the current language in section headings. `titlesec` doesn't like that and raises the error you see.

The issue can be narrowed down to:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{main}{}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{main}
\section{a}
\end{document}
```

The bug has already been fixed. If you're experiencing this problem you need to update `babel`.

Comment: Thanks Phelye, that seems to work just fine! I look forward to an update of babel.

Comment: @PaulWalker `babel` is now updated on CTAN. I've just updated my TeXLive and everything is working now.

Comment: Yes, looks like all is working for me too. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I tried setting the English language and it worked. Try to set encoding options too.

```
\documentclass[english,10pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
%--------------------------------------
%encoding
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Allow to input letters of national alphabets directly from the keyboard.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %choose a font encoding which has to support specific characters for Spanish language

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\Large}{\thechapter}{12mm}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{6mm}{1cm}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large}{\thesection}{8mm}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{5mm}{5mm}
\newpagestyle{main}{
\sethead[\thepage][\chaptertitle][(\thesection] % even
{\thesection)}{\sectiontitle}{\thepage}} % odd
\begin{document}\pagestyle{main}
\chapter{C1}
\section{S1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Does it really? The error is the same for me...

Comment: Tried just english and still got the same error.

Comment: You can see my result:
https://imgur.com/vJlrxyy

Comment: Try set encoding options:

    %--------------------------------------
    %encoding
    %--------------------------------------
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Allow to input letters of national alphabets directly         from the keyboard.
     \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %choose a font encoding which has to support specific    characters for Spanish language

Comment: I've included this in my first answer, try to compile again!

Comment: Tried adding the two lines  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} but still get the error.

Comment: This looks much like a `babel`-`titleps` bug, I just couldn't trace it to the source. Changing language or adding encoding options will be of no use. Thus this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: If its a babel related issue, how does Rogelio get it to run? We both load babel.

Comment: @PaulWalker The issue is due to the 2019-10-01 update of the LaTeX kernel. Rogelio is probably using an older version. As I said, completely unrelated to language or encoding.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, I did an update a few days back.

Comment: Hi, I tried this code using TeXLive 2013. Your could be right, your issue may be due to TL update.

Comment: @RogelioPrieto Wow, 2013?! I highly recommend you update to something newer. TeXLive 2013 is _really_ old now...